# Word 2016/2019 crashes on wdDialogFileNew

Tags: vba, ms-word

Word 2016 / 2019 crashes if you use a macro to open the "old" template dialog via macro.

Has `wdDialogFileNew` been replaced by something else? Are we not allowed to use this anymore? wdDialogFileNew2007 is not really a good alternative since is does not allow you to create new templates based on existing ones.

```
application.dialogs(wdDialogFileNew).show
```

So far it opened the old template dialog, but now it crashes word completely.

Update-1:
At first it seemed that Office Pro Plus 2019 Version 1903 Build 11425.20202 was still usable it (because I thought I missed an update of office, but I already was up to date).

OK ... this is even more weird ... the problems seems to be depended on how many tabs would need to be created for to show all the templates ... even the before mentioned version (*Office Pro Plus 2019 Version 1903 Build 11425.20202*) has the problem after some trial and error. If more than 2 additional tabs need to be created word crashed. This is for User-Templates + Workgroup-Templates. If either or both folder(s) contain more than 2 subfolders that would be shown as tabs, it crashes word.

Comment: And, as I mentioned, please detail the repro steps - the "sub-folders" part. If we take the time to test, it helps to know exactly what needs to be done. This is time out of our working day - we aren't paid for the help we provide here.

Comment: you have the folder for the user-templates "appdata\microsoft\templates". create 3+ subfolders and put a template in each folder. call the macro ... crash happens.

skip the the part with the user-templates-folder: if you define a workgroup-folder = "c:\temp\" ... create 3+ subfolders and put a template in each folder. call the macro ... crash happens.

if you only create 2 subfolders, it works. each folder should appear as an tab in the dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok ... either this is only happening to me or nobody else has an answer.

I simply build my own template-dialog as a replacement. Biggest plus ... it's bigger and therefore offers a bigger selection and it remembers the last directory I last selected a template from.

Comment: Can you please share your solution with me? I am also facing a similar problem when I try to open "old" (older than 2013) template dialogue via macros.
Kindly help, you are not the only one having this problem.

Comment: Sadly I can give my solution in full since I developed it for my company ... I can give you the concept of what I did.

Comment: I used the WORD-VBA to rebuild the dialog. I read through all my user- and then workgroup- template-folders and list the templates in a list-view. Double-click opens one. Since it is my own dialog I can make it bigger and I can tell Word to create a new template from a given one instead of creating just a document. I can also display more info on every template (date, etc.).

I use the "Scripting.FileSystemObject" and "Scripting.Dictionary" to list all the templates and sort them.

Comment: mUsrTplPath = Options.DefaultFilePath(wdUserTemplatesPath)
mWorkGrpTplPath = Options.DefaultFilePath(wdWorkgroupTemplatesPath)